# User Session attached to another user's session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an asp.net web app and i have an issue when two or more users on the same network are logged in . I use a query to retrieve account details which sometimes retrieves the details of the other person logged in on the same network.

**Example**

John are Lisa are logged in with different devices and have need used the same device

Sometime Lisa's Account Details appear as John's details on his account and same happens to lisa.

I am not sure if this issue arises from

```
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

or why lisa can see John's account

Sample Query

```
   // Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

    // Retrieve profile Name

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string selectSql = "SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = (@UserId)";
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(selectSql, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
        Label1.Text = myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: not clear what you are asking.?

Comment: First thing, you could pass the Page.User.Identity.Name property if they are logged in to the Membership provider to help ensure you are getting the right user. 

Can you show us more of the query you are using to get the details based upon the user id? 

Have you verified that the user's ID in the table that holds the details is unique (and not an empty guid for example).

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick thanks, i have edited the question to include a sample query.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick the userid's are unique. Initial when the user logs in, it display there correct details. after login, sometimes it just randomly displays another users details.  When the user refreshes, it displays their correct details

Comment: @user3540365 The question is when can does john sometimes see lisa's details are his?

Comment: @Jack - The behavior you describe sounds like you are using a static variable or a cache somewhere to store the user object or user id. In either of these cases, the user id will be shared among all of the users of the application. This issue is not present in the code you included in the sample, so you will have to check how the currentUser and currentUserId are treated throughout your application.

Comment: @NightOwl888 i am really new to asp.net, and i am not sure how to disable this static variable or check  how userid is handled. Can you please guide me?

Comment: @Jack - Start by doing a search. Press `CTRL + SHIFT + F` in Visual Studio. Type `Membership.GetUser()` in the `Find What` box. In the `Look In` box choose `Entire Solution`. Then click the `Find All` button. From there, look at all of the variable declarations where the value is stored. From any user or user id variable, you can right click and choose `Go To Definition`. Make sure none of them are declared static. Also, make sure the value is never stored in a cache (will look something like `HttpContext.Current.Cache["SomeKey"] = user`).